# Music not playing from file, but works fine in IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, audio, pygame

I have tried to make a sound file work, and from the IDLE 3.6, it works fine.
However when I try to run it from the actual file it breaks and crashes.
The error only says:
'Couldn't open 'Sounds/music.ogg'

This code has the same effect (runs fine from IDLE, breaks from file):

```
try:
    import pygame

    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 300))
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Sounds/music.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops = -1)
except Exception as E:
    print(E)
    input()
```

I've tried other file formats, .mp3 and .wav, and they have the same outcome.
So basically, how can I make the music work fine from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that the sound file is not in the right place. You should have a folder "Sounds" in the same location as you .py file. And of course, the Sounds folder should contain a file "music.ogg".

Another option is to use absolute file paths. This means doing something like this: `pygame.mixer.music.load("C:/SomeFolder/MainFolder/Sounds/music.ogg")`. This tells the program to look at that exact location instead of relative to its position.

Comment: It was in the same folder, the .py and Sounds, but changing the file path to the full version fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough relative paths doesn't seem to work when running outside of Idle. When changing to use the full path to the file everyhing works fine.